# Inserting a New Column with custom value based on a condittion on a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to insert a new column on a pandas data frame with custom values based on a condition. I have written the code as below but it does not work. Am i missing anything here? I dont want to define a list and then insert it because i may not be processing all the data from the dataset. Any easy way to acheive this?

My Original dataset :

```
    NAME    COUNT   AVAILABLE   SUBJECT
11  aa  1   True    MATHS
12  bb  2   False   MATHS
13  cc  3   True    SCIENCE
14  dd  4   False   SOCIAL
1   ee  5   False   ENGLISH
2   ff  6   False   MATHS
3   gg  7   True    SCIENCE
4   hh  8   True    SOCIAL
5   ii  9   True    MATHS

for i in range(df1.shape[0]):
rowIndex = df1.index[i]
print(rowIndex)
if df1.loc[rowIndex].AVAILABLE == 'True':
    if df1.loc[rowIndex].SUBJECT == 'MATHS':
        df1.loc[rowIndex].MINMARK = 40
    elif df1.loc[rowIndex].SUBJECT == 'SCIENCE':
        df1.loc[rowIndex].MINMARK = 30
    elif df1.loc[rowIndex].SUBJECT == 'SOCIAL':
        df1.loc[rowIndex].MINMARK = 35
    elif df1.loc[rowIndex].SUBJECT == 'ENGLISH':
        df1.loc[rowIndex].MINMARK = 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try `map`:

```
df['MINMARK'] = df.SUBJECT.map(
    dict(zip(['MATHS', 'SCIENCE', 'SOCIAL', 'ENGLISH'], [40, 30, 35, 50])))
```

*OR*:

```
df['MINMARK'] = df.SUBJECT.map(
    {'MATHS': 40, 'SCIENCE': 30, 'SOCIAL': 35, 'ENGLISH': 50})
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
   NAME  COUNT  AVAILABLE  SUBJECT  MINMARK
11   aa      1       True    MATHS       40
12   bb      2      False    MATHS       40
13   cc      3       True  SCIENCE       30
14   dd      4      False   SOCIAL       35
1    ee      5      False  ENGLISH       50
2    ff      6      False    MATHS       40
3    gg      7       True  SCIENCE       30
4    hh      8       True   SOCIAL       35
5    ii      9       True    MATHS       40
```

#### UPDATED ANSWER:

use `df.where` for conditional filling.

```
df['MINMARK'] = df.where(df.AVAILABLE).SUBJECT.map({'MATHS': 40, 'SCIENCE' : 30, 'SOCIAL' : 35, 'ENGLISH' : 50})
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
   NAME  COUNT  AVAILABLE  SUBJECT  MINMARK
11   aa      1       True    MATHS     40.0
12   bb      2      False    MATHS      NaN
13   cc      3       True  SCIENCE     30.0
14   dd      4      False   SOCIAL      NaN
1    ee      5      False  ENGLISH      NaN
2    ff      6      False    MATHS      NaN
3    gg      7       True  SCIENCE     30.0
4    hh      8       True   SOCIAL     35.0
5    ii      9       True    MATHS     40.0
```

*NOTE*: You can specify the default value in `where` if required. Additionally, you can also check `np.where`.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is, it fills for the Column which has "AVAILABLE" set to False as well. I want this to filled based my initial condittion of AVAILABLE == 'True"

Comment: @Sai updated my answer. is this okay now?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. Is it okay to ask the follow up queston on the same thread?

Comment: I'll say, Create a new thread if the question is different.  @Sai